# ignore sorting on a particular column tablesorter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

Can I ignore sorting on a particular column in jquery tablesorting plugin?

So basically when the page is loaded I do not not want any sorting done on the column "Search" because it contains images and does some javascript processing of its own and this slows down my sorting considerably.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    jQuery("table").tablesorter({ 


});
```

});

```
    puts "<table cellspacing=\"1px\" class=\"tablesorter\" >"
    puts "<thead>"
    puts "<tr>"
    puts    "<th>Search</th>"
    puts    "<th>Sub-App</th>"
    puts    "<th>Division</th>"
    puts    "<th>Region</th>"
    puts    "<th>Market</th>"
    puts    "<th>Language</th>"
    puts    "<th>Function</th>"
    puts    "<th>LOB</th>"
    puts    "<th>Term</th>"
    puts    "<th>Center</th>"
    puts "</tr>"
    puts "</thead>"
    puts "<tbody>"

    puts "<tr>"
    puts    "<td id=\"$cellID\">"
    puts    "<img src=\"images/magnifier.gif\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" onclick=\"showRouting({'spec':'${specific}', 'id':'${mkt_id}', 'name':'${mkt_name}', 'xfer':'${xfertype}', 'cell':'${cellID}'})\"</img>"
    puts    "</td>"
    puts    "<td>$level</td>"
    puts    "<td>$div_name</td>"
    puts    "<td>$reg_name</td>"
    puts    "<td>$link</td>"
    puts    "<td>$lang</td>"
    puts    "<td>$func</td>"
    puts    "<td>$lob</td>"
    puts    "<td>$term</td>"
    puts    "<td>$ctr_name</td>"
    puts "</tr>"

    puts "</tbody>"
    puts "</table>"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind. the following answers my question. it doesnt sort any faster because it still displays the images on that column.

```
 headers: {
            0: { sorter: false }

        }
```

Answer (score 11):

As per the [documentation](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html), you can now use `class="sorter-false"`

Comment: but be carefully, it's supported only since certain version, probably you had an old one and need to update lib

Answer (score 6):

Add a `noSort` class to the `</td>` header of the columns you don't want sorted and then to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    // Get Headers with Class noSort //
    var theHeaders = {}
    $(this).find('th.noSort').each(function(i,el){
        theHeaders[$(this).index()] = { sorter: false };
    });

    // Initialize Table Sorter //
    $("table").tablesorter({
         headers: theHeaders
    });
});
```

I hope this helps!