# Numareting table with angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create numbered table with angular,

I tried

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
     <td>{{$index}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

it works, but when i sort table using order By i want to remain index-es
so the first "" in tr always must be something like that - 1,2,3,4
and order by changes it 2,1,4,3 and stuff like that

sorry for my bad English

I've added jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9907/

Comment: Just to make sure, you want the first row to always be the number 1, second always 2, etc.?

Comment: Yes exactly first row to always be the number 1 despite of order by changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution i found, with css

```
table{
   counter-reset: rows; /* initalize the counter variable */
}
tr{
counter-increment: rows; /* increment the counter every time a tr is       encountered */
}
td{ /* just for demo */
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
}
td:first-child:before{ /* add the counter value before the first td in every row */
    content: counter(rows) ". ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$index` variable is not a part of your `data` but the array indexes only. When you order the array with different parameter the order of the your `data` array's value changed but array indexes remain same as before. To get ride of this problem you can put a sequential `value` as a property of each object of `data` array. Then show display that property instead of showing the `$index` of data array.

For example in controller:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++){
  $scope.data[i].sl = i+1;
}
```

In view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
     <td>{{item.sl}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But when the sort changes, what happens? I want first td to number 1,2,3,4 and etc. in your example, indexes is ok for first time only, when user changes sort order, sl field value will shuffle, so there wont be 1,2,3,4

Comment: So, you don't want it be be shuffle when you apply order by filter?

Comment: You can try by using `<td>data.indexOf(item)</td>`

Comment: but it wont be asc order, right? when i change sort order indexOf wont change

Comment: Thats the main problem

Comment: You have said that you don't want to change the indexes. You want to keep 1, 2, 3, 4 as 1, 2, 3, 4 ever after applying filter. But now you are saying that " when i change sort order indexOf wont change. Thats the main problem ". So, you want to change index(1, 2, 3, 4) or want to keep it unchange??

Comment: Sorry for confusion and bad english, i dont want change indexes, i wanted to say, that indexOf wont change but the rendered item order will change, so there wont be 1,2,3,4 in case of indexOf, did you get?

Comment: I've just made some jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9907/

Comment: Oh bullshit, I've forgot that i had one time binding, ng-bind="::$index", thats the probem

Comment: congratulation!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to mark the column to not sort, something like this:

```
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
          DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable()
];
```

Example data table:

```
<table dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs"> </table>
```

[Here](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/api) is some docs.

But, to mark some table data as not sortable with Jquery is possible, as @dSquared [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857742/ignore-sorting-on-a-particular-column-tablesorter).

Comment: You wrote example of datatables, i am not using it, just native ng-repeat